# How can I remap the vim record macro key from 'q' to 'Q'?

Tags: vim

Sometimes I accidentally enter vim's record macro mode by pressing 'q' (which I usually get out of by pressing q two more times.)

What are the commands to change the keybinding to start recording a macro from 'q' to 'Q'?

I can stop 'q' from doing anything by setting

```
nnoremap q <Nop>
```

but I'm not sure how to get 'Q' to be the record macro shortcut.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can remap Q to quit and q to no command in two command lines Like this:

```
nnoremap Q q
nnoremap q <Nop>
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer this variant - `,q`, where `,` is `Leader` key:

```
noremap <Leader>q q
noremap q <Nop>
```

`Q` in normal mode performs a standard function, switch to "Ex" mode.